# Unlock keyboard keys

Tags: javascript

I have an input field, and a 3rd party lib blocks certain keys. So for example, it's not possible anymore to type the `,`. Is it possible to remove those key blocks through javascript?

Comment: can't you simply remove the import of js file?

Comment: Yes, it probably is. Have you tried anything? Because ATM, your question is too broad, and way to vague to answer. The way to _"unlock "_ these chars is to delegate a `keypress` event on a higher level, and set the value of the field manually, before the lib can interfere